# C++ recursive pointer function calls

Tags: c++, pointers, pass-by-reference

I currently have a base class `Expr` and some derivatives like `AddExpr`, `MultExpr` and `NumExpr`. I am trying to overload a general `print()` function that recursively calls the `print()` function of its members which are pointers to other `Expr` objects.

```
//Addition Expression
AddExpr::AddExpr( Expr* l, Expr* r ) {
    left = l;
    right = r;
}
string AddExpr::print() {
    string s;
    stringstream out;
    out << "(+" << left->print() << right->print() << ")";
    s = out.str();
}

NumExpr::NumExpr( string n ) {
    number = atoi( n.c_str() );
}
string NumExpr::print() {
    string s;
    stringstream out;
    out << number;
    s = out.str();
    return s;
}
```

So ultimately I want the add expression to print out a ( number + number ) if the left and right pointers are numbers, ( expression + number ), ( expression + expression ), etc. by recursively calling the `print()` function.

However I don't think I'm approaching this correctly as I am getting jumbled output :(
I am not too familiar with pass by pointer and pass by reference, however every post that I have gone through with similar question are not quite relevant to my situation.

Here's a debug sample for calling the functions:

```
NumExpr* left = new NumExpr("1");
cout << left->print() << endl;
NumExpr* right = new NumExpr("2");
cout << right->print() << endl;
AddExpr* temp = new AddExpr( left, right );
cout << temp->print() << endl;
Expr* temp2 = temp;
cout << temp2->print() << endl;
```

This will print out 1 and 2 but has the problem on the AddExpr.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
the header for my expression classes:

```
class Expr {
    public:
        virtual string name();
        virtual string print();
};

class AddExpr : public Expr {
    public:
        AddExpr(Expr* l, Expr* r);
        string print();
    private:
        Expr* left;
        Expr* right;
};

class NumExpr : public Expr {
    public:
        NumExpr( string v );
        string print();
    private:
        int number;
};
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add the complete source code of the relevant classes (`Expr`, `AddExpr`, `NumExpr`)? Also, what is the actual output of your sample, and what did you expect instead?

Comment: You forgot to `return s;` in `AddExpr::print()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AddExpr::print() does not return any value.

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem, the `print()` function is now correctly outputting my expressions. Much appreciated, though I would have hoped g++ would atleast warn me about something like this

Comment: @Jason: It does, but you have to ask it to enable warnings. I usually use `-Wall -Wextra` (and also `-Werror` to turn them into errors, so no-one can ignore them).

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks that's an awesome tip, I usually code in visualstudio on windows side, but unfortunately I don't have access to that at the moment, so I'm doing it via g++ and vim on linux side :) Good experience though.

Answer (score 2):

I see two problems with your AddExpr::print() method:

1. It doesn't actually return anything.  You should have at least gotten a compiler warning, if not an error, for this.
2. It doesn't put any space between `left` and `right`.

Try this:

```
string AddExpr::print() {
    string s;
    stringstream out;
    out << "(+" << left->print() << " " << right->print() << ")";
    s = out.str();
    return s;
}
```

Though actually, it would be better to do the following -- no need to create an explicit string variable:

```
string AddExpr::print() {
    stringstream out;
    out << "(+" << left->print() << " " << right->print() << ")";
    return out.str();
}
```